# JSch executing more than one linux command at once

Tags: java, linux, jsch

My aim is to connect to my linux server using a java application and execute a linux command. I have already achieved this using the JSch API but I can't seem to figure out how to execute more than one command at a time.

It's a problem for me because I need to navigate to a certain directory, then execute another command FROM that directory. My application just exits before the second command can be executed in the correct directory.

Here is my method to execute one linux command as a string when it is passed as a parameter and print any output.

```
public void connect(String command1){

try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          }
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          catch(Exception ee){
              ee.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");

  }
catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to do 2 commands at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a normal shell is started on the remote machine, use `;` or `&&` constructs to do more things.

As in

```
cd /home/foo/banana ; do_things
```

or

```
cd /home/foo/banan && do_things #do_things will only be run if the cd command is successfull
```